# Orderby rotating values in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a sort by feature for "recommended" on my ecommerce site using the `orderBy` method. Here's a sample of a simple orderby:

```
if($params['sortby'] == 'numpricehl') $query->orderBy('price','desc');
```

What I am hoping to do is order by rotating values. Example: Given 10 products priced at: (10,20,30,....100), it would order them like this (low,mid,high,low,mid,high) etc. so that the products would display like this (10,50,100,20,60,80)

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I assume a random order wouldn't be enough?

Comment: No unfortunately, it could be within a range. For example: it could be all values <40 in the low tier and order those from low to high, then values from 41-60 mid tier ordered low to high, then high tier would be 61+ ordered from low to high but the main point is it would loop every 3 values, and each of the loops would be: low,medium,high.

Comment: Are the tiers fixed? What about the remaining products (when the tiers are unevenly "filled")?

Comment: they aren't fixed as prices fluctuate from time to time, so it would have to be based on min, max, and median I suppose. As for the unevenly filled tiers it would have to keep going until it runs out of one category then it would just alternate the remaining categories. Example: (low,mid,high,low,mid,high,mid,high,mid,high,high,high). Or if it's easier just sort by one category once it runs out of one of the three. I hope that answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works on the query result:

```php
$tiers = 3;
$result = [];
$products = Product::orderBy('price')->get();
$size = ceil($products->count() / $tiers);
$split = $products->pluck('price')->chunk($size);
while(!$split[0]->isEmpty()) {
    for($tier = 0; $tier < $tiers; $tier++) {
        if(!$split[$tier]->isEmpty()) {
            $result[] = $split[$tier]->shift();
        }
    }
}
```

There's probably an in-database solution with `orderBy()`, but I'm pretty sure it's more complicated.

The `chunk()` part isn't ideal yet because it splits 10 products into `4,4,2`.

You can add this to get `4,3,3`:

```php
if($products->count() % $tiers == 1) {
    $split[2]->prepend($split[1]->pop());
}
```

Comment: I might be executing this wrong, but I had to use "sortby" since I keep getting either error "method not found orderby" or "method not found split". Anyway it still throws an error but it at least prints some of the values while throwing the error. Here are some of them "array( '39', '28', '158', '135', '109', '110', '115', '105', '135', '110', '107', '134', '110', '156', '164', '132', '121', '140', '154', '161', '137', '132', '126', '186', '134',)., Not exactly how I wanted also.

Comment: How do/did you execute it?

Comment: `$tiers = 3;
$result = [];
            
$products = Package::all()->sortBy('price','desc')->get();
$split = $products->split($tiers);
while($split[0]->isNotEmpty()) {
    for($tier = 0; $tier < $tiers; $tier++) {
        if($split[$tier]->isNotEmpty()) {
            $result[] = $split[$tier]->shift();
        }
    }` And it throws this error along with the data: 
`asort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given`

Comment: Did you try `Package::orderBy('price')->get();`?

Comment: Yes it returns this: `Method split does not exist.`

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: i am using verison: 5.2

Comment: isNotEmpty is not a method, im guessing it's because of the version as well.

Comment: Yes. Use `!...isEmpty()`.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing, I think it works. It's interesting, it's taking the lowest value, an average value, then a value above average but not the highest. I think I can tweak it from here. Thank you so so so much!

Comment: You're welcome. It splits the prices into thirds and takes the first price of each tier. Then the second price of each tier etc. You could maybe randomly shuffle the prices of each tier.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.

Comment: I just did! I wish I could give you a thumbs up but I am too new as a user to be able to.

Comment: Follow up question. I was trying to integrate the function you made for me into the `$query` so that it can be used as a sort by but I am getting the `Method OrderBy Does not exist` error. I think I am implementing wrong. Basically, at the moment it works by returning a list of prices, not the entire package. It also only works if I use the table name and not a variable `$query`. Do you think you can give an example of how I would be able to implement the `$query` into this? `if($params['sortby'] == 'numpricehl') $query->orderBy('price','desc');` is the format Id like.

Comment: Can you add the code to your question? It's easier to read there.

Comment: How the code is: `if(isset($params['sortby'])){
if($params['sortby'] == 'numpricehl') $query->orderBy('price','desc');
if($params['sortby'] == 'numpricelh') $query->orderBy('price','asc');`
What I want: 
` $tiers = 3;
$result = [];
$products = $query->orderBy('price','asc')->get();
$size = ceil($products->count() / $tiers);
$split = $products->pluck('price')->chunk($size);
while(!$split[0]->isEmpty()) {
for($tier = 0; $tier < $tiers; $tier++) {
if(!$split[$tier]->isEmpty()) {
$result[] = $split[$tier]->shift();
 }
}
}
if($params['sortby'] == 'bestmatch') ->$result`

Comment: Sorry about the lack of indentation, I ran out of characters.

Comment: Use the edit feature and add the code to your question.

Comment: How is `$query` created?

Comment: `public function fineSearch($id, $params){
 $regions = Region::where('id','=',$id)->with(['packages' => function($query) use ($params){
                 $query->where('sold','=',0);` 

Then it narrows down the `$query` based on `$params` for different filters and sorting.

Comment: Which table contains the `price` column? `packages`?

Comment: Yes, I wish I had more reputation so I could use the chat feature instead of bombarding this question with comments. Really sorry about that.

Comment: You can't put the code inside the closure. You have to execute the `Region::` query and then use the region's packages.

Comment: I see, so I'd have to restructure the way I am sorting, or make a special case for the best match basically. I think I have a couple of ideas. Thanks again for the help!